# Iniciar sliderextender con un número predeterminado ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estimados estoy haciendo un web form el cual es una forma visual de hacer `WHERE` en una base de datos **SQL**, concretamente tengo un par de dropdown list que se conectan directo a la base donde elijo una tabla y filtro algunos datos. Después de eso habilito a través de `Updatepanel` una serie de controles que van creando un gran `WHERE` para bajar un archivo...

Hasta ahora tengo todo funcionando según lo planeado, pero necesito que un `sliderextender` que se lleno con **C#** muestre un número específico cuando lo habilito, pero por más que le doy la instruccion siempre inicia en 1..

este es el código **HTML**:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel11" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>         
          Desde <asp:TextBox ID="H_Desde" runat="server" Width="38px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox> 
          <asp:TextBox ID="Desde_text" runat="server" Width="128px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox> 
          <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderDesde" runat="server" BehaviorID="Desde_text_Slider" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" EnableHandleAnimation="True" TargetControlID="Desde_text" BoundControlID="H_Desde"/>
          <%--<asp:SliderExtender ID="SliderDesde" runat="server" BehaviorID="Desde_text_Slider" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" TargetControlID="Desde_text" BoundControlID="H_Desde" />--%>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Descp_Casos" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="H_Desde" EventName="TextChanged"/>
     </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

y asi lo lleno y lo intento especificar:

```
try
{
     con.Open();
     ResultadoD = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

     con2.Open();
     ResultadoH = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

     // H_Desde.Text = ResultadoD.ToString();
     minHidro = ResultadoD;
     maxHidro = ResultadoH;
     minHidro = maxHidro - 30;

     SliderDesde.Minimum = ResultadoD;
     SliderDesde.Maximum = ResultadoH;
     SliderHasta.Minimum = ResultadoD;
     SliderHasta.Maximum = ResultadoH;

     minHidro = maxHidro - 30;
     H_Desde.Text = minHidro.ToString();
     H_Hasta.Text = maxHidro.ToString();
```